# A simple web-server is not working after switching to multithread in Erlang

Tags: multithreading, erlang

Here's the code for **rudy.erl**:

```
-module(rudy).
-export([init/1,handler/1,request/1,reply/2, start/1, stop/0]).

start(Port) ->
  register(rudy, spawn(fun() ->
    init(Port) end)).

stop() ->
  exit(whereis(rudy), "time to die").

init(Port) ->
  Opt = [list, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}],
  case gen_tcp:listen(Port, Opt) of         % opens a listening socket
    {ok, Listen} ->
      handler(Listen),
      gen_tcp:close(Listen),            % close the socket
      ok;
    {error, _Error} -> error
  end.

handler(Listen) ->
  case gen_tcp:accept(Listen) of            % listen to the socket
    {ok, Client} ->
      request(Client),
      gen_tcp:close(Client),
      handler(Listen);
    {error, _Error} -> error
  end.

request(Client) ->
  Recv = gen_tcp:recv(Client, 0),
  case Recv of
    {ok, Str} ->
      Request = http:parse_request(Str),
%%       spawn(rudy, reply, [Client, Request]);
      reply(Client, Request);
    {error, Error} ->
      io:format("rudy: error: ~w~n", [Error])
  end.


reply(Client, {{get, URI, _}, _, _}) ->
  timer:sleep(40),
  Response = http:ok(URI),
  gen_tcp:send(Client, Response),
  gen_tcp:close(Client).
```

If I execute `rudy:start(8027)`, it will work normally via accessing **http://localhost:8027/**, but if I convert `reply(Client, Request);` to `spawn(rudy, reply, [Client, Request]);`, the preceding URL could not be accessed with no error output to command line.

What's the possible problem here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a race condition where the socket gets closed before the spawned process can reply. The `handler/1` function calls `request/1`, and that's where the `spawn` occurs to send the reply. Once `spawn` starts the new process to call `reply/2`, it returns immediately and `request/1` then returns to `handler/1`, which immediately closes the socket while `reply/2` is executing in the new process and still trying to use the socket.

You can just remove the `gen_tcp:close/1` call from `handler/1` since the `reply/2` function calls it after replying.

If you want to see an example of a small HTTP server in Erlang, see my [simple web server](https://gist.github.com/vinoski/4996859).

Comment: Another problem pop up to me, could you take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416651/simulation-of-thread-pool-for-a-web-server-implemented-by-erlang-doesnt-work? Thanks bro!