# Simulation of Thread Pool for a web-server implemented by Erlang doesn't work

Tags: multithreading, erlang

The code is as follows:

```
-module(rudy).
-export([init/1,handler/1,request/1,reply/1, start/1, stop/0]).

start(Port) ->
  register(rudy, spawn(fun() ->
    init(Port) end)).

stop() ->
  exit(whereis(rudy), "time to die").

init(Port) ->
  Opt = [list, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}],
  case gen_tcp:listen(Port, Opt) of         % opens a listening socket
    {ok, Listen} ->
      spawn_many(3,Listen),
%%       handler(Listen),
      ok;
    {error, _Error} -> error
  end.

handler(Listen) ->
  case gen_tcp:accept(Listen) of            % listen to the socket
    {ok, Client} ->
      request(Client),
      gen_tcp:close(Client),
      handler(Listen);
    {error, _Error} -> error
  end.
%%   gen_tcp:close(Listen).            % close the socket

request(Client) ->
  Recv = gen_tcp:recv(Client, 0),
  case Recv of
    {ok, Str} ->
      Request = http:parse_request(Str),
      Response = reply(Request),
      gen_tcp:send(Client, Response);
    {error, Error} ->
      io:format("rudy: error: ~w~n", [Error])
  end,
  gen_tcp:close(Client).

reply({{get, URI, _}, _, _}) ->
  timer:sleep(40),
  http:ok(URI).

spawn_many(0, _Listen)-> ok;
spawn_many(N, Listen)->
  spawn(rudy,handler,[Listen]),
  spawn_many(N - 1, Listen).
```

I intend to create 3 listening socket for client to connect to, but this code doesn't work when executing `rudy:start(8027).` and then accessing **http://localhost:8027/** from web browser.

Where's the culprit? Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to know about Erlang sockets is that a process that opens one controls it; when that process dies, the runtime closes the socket.

Consider your `start/1` function:

```
start(Port) ->
  register(rudy, spawn(fun() ->
    init(Port) end)).
```

It spawns the `init/1` function, registers a name for it, and then returns. This means `init/1` is running in a new process, so let's look at `init/1`:

```
init(Port) ->
  Opt = [list, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}],
  case gen_tcp:listen(Port, Opt) of         % opens a listening socket
    {ok, Listen} ->
      spawn_many(3,Listen),
%%       handler(Listen),
      ok;
    {error, _Error} -> error
  end.
```

The newly-spawned process running `init/1` first calls `gen_tcp:listen/2`. If it succeeds, it calls `spawn_many/2` to set up some acceptors; if it fails, it essentially ignores the error. But here's the key to your problem: regardless of success or failure, `init/1` ends, and therefore so does the process in which it was spawned, and because this process, the controlling process of the listen socket, dies, the listen socket is closed. Any acceptors trying to use that socket fail because of that, which you would see if you were to print out the error condition in the `handler/1` function.

The way to fix this is to make the `init/1` process wait until all processes using the listen socket die off.

One way to do this is to make `init/1` pass its pid to `spawn_many` (thus changing it from `spawn_many/2` to `spawn_many/3`), have `init/1` wait for 3 messages before exiting, and change `handler/1` to `handler/2`, taking the pid as an additional argument and sending a message there when it's finished. Th easiest way to have `init/1` wait for all the messages is to have it call a recursive function like the one below:

```
init(Port) ->
  Opt = [list, {active, false}, {reuseaddr, true}],
  case gen_tcp:listen(Port, Opt) of         % opens a listening socket
    {ok, Listen} ->
      Count = 3,
      spawn_many(Count,Listen,self()),
      wait_for_threads(Count);
      %%       handler(Listen),
    {error, _Error} ->
      error
  end.

wait_for_threads(0) ->
  ok;
wait_for_threads(Count) ->
  receive
    handler_done ->
      wait_for_threads(Count-1)
  end.
```

Then change `handler/1` to `handler/2` and have it send the message:

```
handler(Listen, Pid) ->
  case gen_tcp:accept(Listen) of            % listen to the socket
    {ok, Client} ->
      request(Client),
      gen_tcp:close(Client),
      handler(Listen, Pid);
    {error, _Error} ->
      error
  end,
  Pid ! handler_done.
```

Don't forget to accept the additional pid argument to `spawn_many/3`:

```
spawn_many(0, _Listen, _Pid)-> ok;
spawn_many(N, Listen, Pid)->
    spawn(rudy,handler,[Listen, Pid]),
    spawn_many(N - 1, Listen, Pid).
```

All this is enough to keep the listen socket alive for all the spawned acceptors.

Comment: Thanks again, I'm new to Erlang, your detailed answer is great help :]